# php mysql select multiple id's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i have 3 tables `customer` `class` `students`.....
**this is my table structure:**

```
customer   = customer_id, name, email
class      = class_id, customer_id, classname
students   = students_id, customer_id, firstname, image
```

customer table using for user login account

i had used the following query to get data from my `students` table under `custmer_id`

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "students WHERE 
customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {     
     $students_data[$result['students_id']] = array(
            'students_id'          => $result['students_id'],
            'class_id'             => $result['class_id'],
            'firstname'            => $result['firstname'],
            'image'                => $result['image'],
    );
}
```

but its look like no matter how many students i added inside my `students` table that all are returning each classroom. I had added 3 classes also inside my `class` table for example: class1 class2 class3, i want to display students who were added under class1 only, if i run class2 and class3, the same who the sames students are returned.

Can I get some help on how to properly query this?

Comment: I fail to see how this could possibly work. you don't have a `customer_id` field in your students table.

Comment: ohh sorry, i had customer_id field my students table... i just missed it, i had edited my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, I believe you need to connect your `students` table to your `customers` table (or to your classes table, but it makes less sense).  Then you can get your result using simple join something like...

```
SELECT  student_id, class_id, firstname, image
FROM    students s,
        class c,
        customer u
WHERE   u.customer_id = c.customer_id
AND     s.customer_id = c.customer_id
AND     c.customer_id = $this->customer->getId()
```

or something to that effect, after you add a `customer_id` column to your students table.

Comment: when i tried this query i get following error:  Notice: Error: Column 'class_id' in field list is ambiguous
Error No: 1052
SELECT students_id, class_id, firstname, image FROM students s, class c, customer u WHERE u.customer_id = c.customer_id AND s.customer_id = c.customer_id AND c.customer_id = '1' in

Comment: based on the columns you listed that should not of been ambiguous.  change the first line to `SELECT  student_id, c.class_id, firstname, image` to prevent this

Answer (score 1):

First you need add a reference column in students table.
Then If you want to get the data class wise, just use **group by** class_id. Any way you need make your question very clear.

Comment: yes, your answer is really what i mean my question... will you explain  how is it.?

Comment: use a group by on Class_ID son.

Comment: but using group by clause on it..you will get any aggregate data of studetns classwise..like number of students classwise.

Answer (score 0):

just add to your WHERE clause, and WHERE class_id in (Class1)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a link table between customers and classes.

Simplify the `class` table by removing the `customer_id` from it.

Then create a `Student_has_Class` table that has a looks like this

```
Student_has_Class = student_id, class_id
```

Then you can just query that table to find which students are assigned to which class.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT class_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "Student_has_Class WHERE 
student_id = '" . $studentId . "'");
```